# How can you stop a running ASIHTTPNetworkQueue?

Tags: iphone, xcode, asihttprequest

I am wondering how you can stop a running ASIHTTPNetworkQueue ?
Is it somehow possible? Because when I dismiss my view where the network queue is set up, my app crashes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) you would use

[queue cancelAllOperations];

I'd suggest though that you may wish to consider placing all your core networking in a single shared data model class as that way you don't have problems with view controllers coming and going.

Comment: Right, and be careful about any delegates.  Read all of Ben's doco on the subject carefully!